# Email encoding on IIS7

Tags: php, iis-7, encoding, email

All emails sent from the server are displaying Cyrillic letters as weird characters, for example: `ÐœÐ¾Ð¶Ð½Ð¾`.

Regular alphabet letters are properly rendered.

I searched all across the web but was not able to find any solutions.

Here is some information about the system:

- Dedicated server with Windows 2008 and IIS7
- Application are in PHP (run as FastCGI)
- If of any importance, [Smartermail](http://smartertools.com/smartermail/mail-server-software.aspx) is installed on the server

The emails are sent using PHPs `mail()` function through a [Drupal](http://drupal.org) website. Encoding on that site is set up properly and there are no display issues on front end.

Where is the problem? How can I make Cyrillic letters to be properly encoded?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

Here are the email headers:

`Received: from SERVERNAME (mail.domain.com [12.123.123.123]) by mail.domain.com with SMTP; Fri, 16 Nov 2012 00:00:00 +0100

From: email@domain.com

To: email2@domain.com

Subject: Email subject

Date: Fri, 16 Nov 2012 00:00:00 +0100

MIME-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: text/plain;

    charset="utf-8"

Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

X-Mailer: Drupal

Sender: email@domain.com

Return-Path: email@domain.com

Message-ID: f98b801988c642ef911ef46f7cace92b@com

X-SmarterMail-Spam: SPF_None, ISpamAssassin 8 [raw: 5], DK_None, DKIM_None, Custom Rules []
X-SmarterMail-TotalSpamWeight: 8`

Comment: Ivan, you need to provide more information about your setup, configuration and environment for us to even understand what problem you are having.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Brent :) I updated my post. Let me know if I should post some other information as well.

Comment: No, a little more is needed, what is sending the messages, how are they actually being sent, etc.

Comment: Add that broken message headers to the question, it is impossible to guess correctly otherwise.

Comment: Are you sure this is an e-mail send problem and not an e-mail client display problem?

Comment: @Brent I'd say so - the same happens when I send the same email to gmail, Yahoo or other third party email servers.

Comment: The reason I ask is the charset in the mail headers specify UTF-8 so the characters should be displayed properly.  So it's going wrong somewhere either in your PHP code or the mail server itself.

Comment: It's default Drupal (CMS) function that sends out emails, so I guess the issue is on the mail server. Do you have any hints/ideas what might be wrong with the mail server?

Comment: No, but feel free to open other specific questions regarding your mail server and anything you find there.  This question thread isn't going to provide much more information for you.